# JPA - How to use @OneToMany mappedBy property for different fields in a generic structure?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two related entity objects.

Class `A` inherits from generic `Base` class.

```
@Entity
public class A extends Base<B> {

}

@Entity
public class B {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;

}
```

Similar for class `C`;

```
@Entity
public class C extends Base<D> {

}

@Entity
public class D {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private C c;

}
```

with `Base` class;

```
@Entity
public class Base<T> {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "{both a & c here?}", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<T> set;
}
```

How can I  make `mappedBy` property on the `Base` support two different values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about renaming both `@ManyToOne` annotated *parent* fields with the same name?

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private A parent;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private C parent;
```

then you can have;

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
Set<T> set;
```

for you cannot pass a non-constant value as an annotation parameter.